# Process only some messages from a message queue

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I have a message queue where i add some emails.
I want to extract all emails, examine the date when they were added and their priority and send only one of them.
I read messages like this:

```
private IList<Email> GetEmailsFromQueue(MessageQueue queue)
{
    queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Email) });
    IList<Email> emails = new List<Email>();
    Cursor cursor = queue.CreateCursor();
    Message m = PeekWithoutTimeout(queue, cursor, PeekAction.Current);
    if (m != null)
    {
        emails.Add((Email)m.Body);
        while ((m = PeekWithoutTimeout(queue, cursor, PeekAction.Next)) != null)
        {
            emails.Add((Email)m.Body);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}

private Message PeekWithoutTimeout(MessageQueue q, Cursor cursor, PeekAction action)
{            
    Message msgFromQueue = null;
    try
    {
        msgFromQueue = q.Peek(new TimeSpan(1), cursor, action);
    }
    catch(MessageQueueException ex)
    {
        if (!ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("timeout"))
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return msgFromQueue;
}
```

Receive method will remove the message from the queue.
Is there any way to read and remove only some messages?

LE: One solution i mighty think of is to add an id to each message, and use ReceiveById

Any other tips?

Comment: Maybe nservicebus is an option for you? http://www.nservicebus.com/
It's a framwork around MSMQ that sends messages through a queue and uses handlers to process specific messages.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do this *Is there any way to read and remove only some messages?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to read and remove only some messages?

I've never used MSMQ (well not in anger anyways) but I think you should be able to combine both the `Peek` and `ReceiveById` methods.

So you would continue to `Peek` at the queue to see what messages are available and then once you have decided to remove a message make use of the `ReceiveById`, to process/remove from the queue.

Aside from this perhaps the other option would be to make use of 2 queues. The first would be for all inbound messages and the second would be used to add back messages you want to keep.

So going back to your example (assuming I understand what you're trying to achieve)

- the first would be for inbound emails which you process as described *extract all emails, examine the date when they were added and their priority*
- the second would be for your outbound emails i.e. once you have the email you want to send, push it on to the outbound queue

Comment: Is this method preferable to creating separate queues for each account/channel/user?

Comment: not 100% sure what you mean but i suspect multiple queues provides great flexibility - also the peek / receive approach leaves uncertainty; in that you're never sure if a messages have been processed - instead having inbound queue makes it clear that messages still need to be processed and the outbound queue makes it clear they 'have' been processed